# How to run parallel excel macros with PowerShell?

Tags: excel, vba, multithreading, powershell, parallel-processing

I would like to run multiple excel macros in parallel by opening multiple instances of excel using a shell (PowerShell) script.

Examples on parallel processing in shell aren't intuitive to me (new to shell scripting).

```
# start excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

# get files
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\User\test"

# loop through all files in the directory
ForEach ($file in $files){

    # open the file
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)

    # make file visible
    $excel.Visible = $true

    # run macro
    $app = $excel.Application
    $app.run("Macro1")
}
```

The code provided performs the task I want, but it does so sequentially rather than in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app.run("application.ontime vba.now() + vba.timeserial(0,0,5),""Macro1"" ")
```

This will run assync your macro , but still dont know if is that you want